# ros2 gazebo without GUI

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros2, roslaunch, gui

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does someone have a way to launch gazebo without GUI from launch file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/376834/ros2-gazebo-without-gui/) by [avzmpy](https://answers.ros.org/users/56476/avzmpy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2021-04-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use `launch.actions.ExecuteProcess` to launch Gazebo.

So let's say your normal Gazebo process looks like this:

```
    ...
    gz_process = ExecuteProcess(cmd=`gazebo`, '--verbose', LaunchConfiguration('world'),
                                    '-s', 'libgazebo_ros_factory.so'], output='screen')
    ...
       return LaunchDescription([
         ...
            DeclareLaunchArgument(name='world', default_value=default_world_path,
                                  description='Absolute path to SDF world file'),
            gz_process,
         ...
        ])
```

Instead of calling `gazebo` there, you can call `gzserver`. You can do this using a Launch Argument or just a seperate launch file all together.

---

Originally posted by [vinny](https://answers.ros.org/users/52902/vinny/) with karma: 291 on 2021-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1